# How can i clear setInterval function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I did a demo for set Interval but confused on clear Interval. Here i am write full demo code.
Please improve it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.done').click(function() {
    $('.def').show(400).hide(5800);
    if ($('.def').css('display') == 'block') {
      $('.def').addClass('aa');
    }
  });
  setInterval(
    function abc() {
      if ($('.def.aa').css('display') == 'none' && $(window).scrollTop() >= 0) {
        console.log(8);
        $('.def.aa').removeClass('aa');
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: $('.done').offset().top - 5
        }, 400);
        return false;
      }
    }, 400);

});
```

```css
.abc {
  color: red;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: cursive;
}
.def {
  color: black;
  font-size: 29px;
}
.done {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: fantasy;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <p class="abc">Demo Text Demo Text Demo Text</p>
  <p class="def" style="display: none">show this</p>
  <a href="/" class="done">Click Me</a>
</div>
```

In this Set Interval is working fine but may be due to clear Interval browser have hanging problem.

Comment: clearInterval: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval#Example

Comment: You need to call clearInterval, set the object return by setInterval and later pass to clearInterval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the interval in **setInterval()**

```
var myVar = setInterval(function(){}, 1000);
```

Clear the interval

```
clearInterval(myVar);
```

Answer (score 1):

Set your interval into a variable and clean this variable

```
var inter = setInterval(function(){}, 1000);
clearInterval(inter);
```

---

*Reference*

- [clearInterval MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval)

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign return value from `setInterval` to a variable.

Add that variable out of your function like

```
var myInterval = 0;
```

then in your function add `myInterval = setInterval ...`
and when you want to clear it just call `clearInterval(myInterval);`